# Adding to blacksmithing in VTM

Tags: world-of-darkness, crafting, vampire-the-masquerade, demon-the-fallen

In a VTM 20th campaign I'm playing a Ventrue vampire that is a modern age blacksmith, he have an architect nature and crafting is his life.

Now, he really likes to craft weapons, mainly swords, and he's also good at using then in combat.
But recently I started to look into ways to make his crafts more powerful, and speaking with my DM he said that he remembered seeing some thing about magical crafting in the Demon: the fallen system, and as my character is contracted with a demon and knows dark thaumaturgy (path of fire), he could learn it.

But searching in all books from the World of Darkness series I only found the special effect in crafting from the higher levels of potence (6 and 7) but nothing on the DTF system, does anyone know where I can find it or if there are any other ways of enhancing his craft?

Comment: For what it's worth, the demons one contracts with using Dark Thaumaturgy aren't of the same kind that the Fallen are — they're not PC capable and don't have PC powers. Fallen's it's own thing.

Comment: Didn't know that, but I think he just wanted a system to base his feature upon, like, he would create his own thing based on DTF

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Blood Tempering

Find an Assamite buddy who'll perform (or teach) this Combination Discipline power (Quietus ••••, Fortitude ••). It originates in the Dark Ages (*Libellus Sanguinis III* 67, *DA20* 248) and imbues an object with soak dice equal to the user's Stamina + Fortitude and increases the damage rating of weapons by 1.

Answer (score 0):

## Ask your ST if you can adapt mortal Linear Sorcery into a Thaumaturgy Path.

In the book Sorceror Revised, there are a number of different Paths for mortal Linear Sorcerors; effectively, they're the mortal equivalent of vampire Thaumaturgy. As such, it might be plausible for a vampire who learns one to develop it into a form of vampire Thaumaturgy. In particular, you'd be most interested in the Path of Enchantment, which allows you to create a wide variety of magic items.